# WP8 mono game blackscreen without debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, monogame

I went in to a fustrating problem. I am developing a game using mono games 3.2. My primary platform is WP8 and I am using VS12 express SDK.

Everything is working actually very well as long as I got a debugger detached to my emulator or device. But when I start up the game without a debugger my game doesn't work. Just a black screen, nothing else. I can't even navigate back via the back key.

I tested this with every emulator and with a few devices, each of them resulting into the same black screen.

I uninstalled mono games, reinstalled it. Tried different versions of mono games, but nothing works. The game even passed certification and is submitted in the windows store as beta project. How is this possible that the game works fine with a debugger but doesn't even start up without one?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(8, 0))
                tempID = UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID2") as string;
            else
                tempID = UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID") as string;
```

The problem was not Mono Game. This is the fixed code but my error occured because I tried to get ANID from a windows 8 device instead of ANID2.

And the answer to why the game was running only whit a debugger attached to it is that I had to give my emulator it's own ID. So the game never went through the lines of code above when the debugger was attached.